# openslam_gmapping or slam_gmapping?

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am a beginner with ROS, i successfully installed ROS indigo on my Ubuntu laptop and now i want to install a slam solution to test with my robot. I was searching for gmapping and found out that there are two gmappping packages available to download out there. this may be a very newbie question but could somebody please tell me what is the difference between **openslam_gmapping** and **slam_gmapping** packages?

which one is better to download and install?

I really appreciate the answer.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225602/openslam_gmapping-or-slam_gmapping?/) by [hyena07](https://answers.ros.org/users/25816/hyena07/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-02-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

both is required. slam_gmapping is the package you are looking at but it relies on openslam_gmapping for dependencies.

---

Originally posted by [learner88](https://answers.ros.org/users/25005/learner88/) with karma: 20 on 2016-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Subodh Malgonde](https://answers.ros.org/users/36410/subodh-malgonde/) on 2018-08-08**:
How to install openslam_gmapping? I can't find the github repository for the ros package. I am on melodic.

**Comment by [nigeno](https://answers.ros.org/users/91893/nigeno/) on 2021-12-20**:
You install openslam_gmapping in the same way as slam_gmapping installed: clone git and build the package.
Link for both packages: https://github.com/Project-MANAS/slam_gmapping